# Error 87 when using AnalyseComponentStore on Windows 10 after upgrading from Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, powershell, dism

Here is what I get in a Powershell (run as admin):

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Dism.exe /online /Cleanup-Image /AnalyseComponentStore

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 10.0.15063.0

Image Version: 10.0.15063.0


Error: 87

The analysecomponentstore option is not recognized in this context.
For more information, refer to the help.

The DISM log file can be found at C:\Windows\Logs\DISM\dism.log
```

The error seems to be when the command is run on version of Windows other than 8 or 10. I have Windows 10 Pro, but I recently upgraded from Windows 7 Ultimate.

How can I solve this error?

---

Also when I run the command /StartComponentCleanup, I don't have any error.

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> dism /online /Cleanup-Image /StartComponentCleanup

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 10.0.15063.0

Image Version: 10.0.15063.0

[==========================100.0%==========================]
The operation completed successfully.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I run the command in a Command Prompt run as admin and I didn't get any error. Still I am curious to know why it didn't work in Powershell run as admin.

Comment: Please accept your own answer so that others can benefit from it. :-)

Comment: @Cown I can only do it in 2 days!

Comment: In two days then. :)

Answer (score 1):

It's a syntax error. Try AnalyzeComponentStore, with a z

Comment: Author indicates the original command worked but required Administrator permissions

Comment: @Ramhound, it worked with Administrator permission but in CMD. I didn't have any solution in for Powershell